# How to get perl stderr to httpd log file when using syslog

Tags: perl, apache, logging, centos, syslog

This question is about HTTPD (Apache) 2.? on centOS and modperl 1.7+

When I use the apache directive ErrorLog logs/error_log, my perl warnings show up in the error_log file. When I change this to ErrorLog syslog:local1, **no perl warnings show up in the syslog target.** My question is, how do I remedy this??

(syslog reads: local1.*   /var/log/httpd_error)

Current Apache docs say this

> A very wide variety of different
>   messages can appear in the error log.
>   Most look similar to the example
>   above. The error log will also contain
>   debugging output from CGI scripts. Any
>   information written to stderr by a CGI
>   script will be copied directly to the
>   error log.

Old Apache (1.3) docs talk about something called HookStderr and stderr being sent to /dev/null. I tried using this and configtest fails.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: For the apache config, Serverfault is probably more appropriate. If you want to have your perl script directly log to syslog, see Sys::Syslog (or log4perl, or log dispatch, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/241751/how-to-get-perl-stderr-to-httpd-log-file-when-using-syslog